# re-start animation with start button with burst-engine and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a simple animation with burst engine and html5

I want to connect the start button so that if I press it twice the animation will restart.
now it just start and nothing more happens.  I know it because the start button just give the pause function false value, but I have no clue about how to write the function.

Any ideas ?
I'm using the Burst-Engine library

```
var dVal = 120, redRectTL, blueRectTL;

function minBurstFunk(Burst) {
    //Bakgrunden
    Burst.timeline("bg", 0, 1, 0, false)
        .shape("ruta", "SVG-ex.svg", "svg", 0, 0)
            .cut("redSqr;blueSqr");

    Burst.timeline("bg").paused = true;
    Burst.timeline("redRect", 0, 20, 0.2, true)
            .shape("red", "SVG-ex.svg", "svg", 0, 0)
                .cut("blueSqr;bgSqr;").track("left")
                    .key(0, 0, "easeInOutQuad")
                    .key(10, -50, "linear")
                    .key(20, 0);


    redRectTL = Burst.timeline("redRect");
    redRectTL.paused = true;

    Burst.start("bg;redRect;blueRect");
}

new Burst('loadCanvas', minBurstFunk);

// ************ buttons ******************

//Stoppa red rectangel
function stopRect1() {
    redRectTL.paused = true;
};

//Starta red rectangel
function klickHant() {
    redRectTL.paused = false;
};
```

Link to my animation

http://www.pixeltouch.no/multimedia/labb3/canvas.php

Comment: an online example of your code can help us in solving the problem

Comment: ofcourse. 

This is the link to the animation.

http://www.pixeltouch.no/multimedia/labb3/canvas.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an easy function

Just changed the klickHant() funktion to

```
function klickHant()
    {
    redRectTL.paused = false;
    redRectTL.frame = 0;

    };
```